# How to play Base 64 encoded audio in Android

Tags: android, audio, base64, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play some base 64 encoded audio in Android, and I've followed various examples to come up with the following code:

```
MediaPlayer soundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    soundPlayer.setDataSource(audioData);

    soundPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    });

    soundPlayer.prepare();
    soundPlayer.setVolume(100f, 100f);
    soundPlayer.setLooping(false);
    soundPlayer.start();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When this code executes, I just get silence - and the following error:

> 08-24 11:38:58.555: W/System.err(18862): java.io.IOException: Prepare
>   failed.: status=0x1 08-24 11:38:58.555: W/System.err(18862):  at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method) 08-24 11:38:58.555:
>   W/System.err(18862):  at
>   application.main.Application$27.run(Application.java:233)

Would appreciate if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong. The 'audioData' variable in question (*which, if you manage to decode and play it, describes my frustration*) is as follows:

> data:application/octet-stream;base64,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

Answer (score 2):

Example Code of Playing Base64 encoded audio in Android :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    String base64FormattedString="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";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=findViewById(R.id.btnId);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playMedia();
            }
        });
    }

    public void playMedia() {
        try{
            String url = "data:audio/mp3;base64,"+base64FormattedString;
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(100f, 100f);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the DataSource correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the DataSource correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the DataSource correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                    player.start();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also : [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) is recommend to  play a single audio resource for Java applications.

Comment: Did that actually work for you? Can't seem to get it to work for me.

Comment: Yes its work for me.I tested in two devices,its work completely fine.

Comment: Can't get it to work for me, I just get the error: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1. What version of Android are you using?

Comment: I tested in android nought and redmi note 3s.

Comment: Must be the version of Android I'm using, it's pretty old (SDK version 18). I'm now looking at your other suggestion, using AudioTrack.

Comment: Ok i will check in android sdk 18 and i will reply soon.

Comment: I have updated my answer code.Please let me know, if the issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will give that a go when I’m home later.

Comment: Still not working for me. It never reaches player.start() because I get the error finishSetDataSource_l() dataSource is NULL, return UNKNOWN_ERROR. Are you definitely using the audio data I provided? And is it right that the url now starts with 'data:audio/mp3;base64,data:application/octet-stream;base64,'?

Comment: I am using your audio data  base64 that your provided and in my answer i already set audio data that you provided in your question.Have you tried to play other url data ,mean online url or other in your app? Try below link,let me know its working or not for you.Link:https://www.android-examples.com/stream-play-online-audio-mp3-from-url-in-android/

Comment: Yes, that works fine. It just doesn't seem to work with the data I've provided. I can also play audio samples from files that I have stored locally in the same way.

Comment: I have updated my answer and also I uploaded full example project demo on my drive.Try to run this :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CEgprdR5xDT5-QGphe1QOUxEDXiGBVHR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, I will do this later.

Comment: Have you tried my code?Let me know you you face any issue.

Comment: Yes, it never worked for the data I provided (which was apparently Opus encoded). I had to refactor how I recorded audio in the first place to convert to mp3 first, and now it plays via my existing method. I do appreciate your time though, thank you.

Comment: No,its worked for data that you provided.In your data of base64 ,just remove "data:application/octet-stream;base64," .I already change your base64 string in my answer.See variable "base64FormattedString" in my answer.

Comment: Done all that mate. Didn’t work. It might work on a newer device, or whatever emulator you were using, but on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (which I’m using to guarantee compatibility on older devices) it just doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

your error occurred because of the length of the base64 url limitation. media cannot prepare datasource for the long string. what I found base64 url for around 128 characters maybe work well. For long string you have to split string into pieces and fetch base64 url for small strings.

Answer (score 0):

it's like angry sound.
You can try this code:

```
public void testPlay(View View) {
    String inputFile=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();

    File file= new File(inputFile);
    if (!file.exists()){ file.mkdirs(); }
    String file_name=inputFile+"/"+ "Play.mp3";

    Toast.makeText(this, "Successful file and folder creation.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String strAudio = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,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";
    int iPos = strAudio.indexOf(",");
    String strAudio0 = strAudio.substring(iPos+1);
    try{
        File savefile = new File(file_name);
        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savefile); 
        fos.write(Base64.decode(strAudio0.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)); 
        fos.close();

        myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completion R..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    myPlayer.stop();
                    myPlayer.release();
                }
            });

        myPlayer.setDataSource(savefile.getAbsolutePath());
        myPlayer.prepare();
        myPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to declared myPlayer variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer myPlayer;
```